# Compilar archivos en C usando OS X

Tags: c, codificación, macos

hace dos meses hice un pregunta relacionada a la compilación de multiples archivos en C, estoy usando OS X, pero para GNU/Linux seria igual. Mi pregunta es como compilar los siguientes tres archivos desde la terminal: main.c racional.c racional.h

```
//Código racional.h

struct racional{
    int numerador;
    int denominador;
};

typedef struct racional RACIONAL;

//Definicion de operaciones

RACIONAL crear();
RACIONAL sumar(RACIONAL r, RACIONAL q);
void mostar(RACIONAL r);
void obtenerNum(RACIONAL r);
int obtenerDen(RACIONAL r);
```

---

```
//Código racional.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "racional.h"
//Implementacion de operaciones

RACIONAL crear(){
    RACIONAL a;
    printf("Ingrese numerador: "); scanf("%d", &a.numerador);
    printf("Ingrese denominador: "); scanf("%d", &a.denominador);
return a;
}

RACIONAL sumar(RACIONAL r, RACIONAL q){
    RACIONAL a;
    a.numerador= r.numerador*q.denominador + q.numerador*r.denominador;
    a.denominador= r.denominador*q.denominador;
return a;
}

void mostar(RACIONAL r){
    printf("%d/%d\n", r.numerador, r.denominador);
}

int obtenerNum(RACIONAL r){
return r.numerador;
}

int obtenerDen(RACIONAL r){
return r.denominador;
}
```

---

```
//Código main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "racional.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    /* code */
    RACIONAL b, c, d;

    printf("Primer racional\n");
    b= crear();
    printf("Numerador ingresado: %d\n", obtenerNum(b));
    printf("Denominador ingresado: %d\n", obtenerDen(b));

    printf("Segundo rarcional \n");
    c= crear();
    printf("Numerador ingresado: %d\n", obtenerNum(c));
    printf("Denominador ingresado: %d\n", obtenerDen(c));

    printf("Suma\n");
    d= sumar(b,c);
    mostrar(d);

return 0;
}
```

No funciona escribiendo en la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo en la terminal: gcc -o salida racional.h racional.c main.c y luego ./salida
Me arroja el siguiente error: *clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files*
Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando GCC que tiene OS X es llamado LLVM-GCC y suele ser customizado por Apple para el uso de Xcode, así que te sugiero usar el comando `clang`, más información de las diferencias entre ellos [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708610/llvm-vs-clang-on-os-x)

Yendo a la solución, primero que nada hay un par de errores:

- Es necesario cambiar `void obtenerNum(RACIONAL r);` a `int obtenerNum(RACIONAL r);` en el archivo `racional.h`
- Es necesario cambiar `mostar(RACIONAL r)` a `mostrar(RACIONAL r)` en los archivos `racional.h` y `racional.c` dado que es así como se usa en `main.c`

Por último utiliza este comando dentro de la carpeta de los archivos para compilar:

```
clang racional.c main.c -o salida
```

Y esto para ejecutarlo

```
./salida
```

Espero te sea de ayuda :)

Comment: No funciona, sale el siguiente error: _clang main.c racional.c  -o salida
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mostrar", referenced from:
      _main in main-181618.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)_

Comment: @Fesa, ese error se produce por no hacer la segunda corrección que menciono. cambiar `mostar` por `mostrar` en los archivos `racional.h` y `racional.c`, el log lo muestra claramente con "_mostrar" undefined. Quizas olvidaste guardar los archivos luego de los cambios.

Comment: Tener razón, estaba saturado y ya ni leía los errores, muchas gracias! no podia hacer que funcione.

Comment: De nada, un gusto haberte ayudado :)